# Integration over $\mathbb S^2$ of a particular type of form

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I am wondering (and I am almost certain there is, given how frequently these pop up) if there is any literature on integrals of the following form.

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear transformation and let $\omega = x  \ dy \wedge dz - y  \ dx \wedge dz + z \  dx \wedge dy$. Then I would like to evaluate:

$$\int_{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb S^2} (\exp \circ\, T)(x,y,z)\omega.$$

Answer (score 0):

The integral can be evaluated relatively simply.

The restriction of $\omega$ to $S^2$ is the standard volume form on $S^2$. This can be seen by taking $n=x\partial_x+y\partial_y+z\partial_z$, which restricts to the unit normal on $S^2$, and, and satisfies $\iota_n(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)=\omega$.

We may always choose coordintes so that $T(x,y,z)=kz$ for some $k\ge 0$. Using the associated spherical polar coordinates $(x,y,z)=(r\cos(\theta)\sin(\varphi),r\sin(\theta)\cos(\varphi),r\cos(\varphi))$, we have $T(r,\theta,\varphi)=kr\cos(\varphi)$. Setting, $r=1$, and using the fact that the standard volume form on the sphere is $\sin(\theta)d\theta\ d\varphi$, we can write the integral as
$$
\int_{S^2}e^{T(x)}\omega=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{k\cos(\varphi)}\sin(\varphi)d\theta\ d\varphi
$$
This integral can be evaluated by a substitution.

Comment: What do you mean by "chosen so that T is proportional to the $z$ coordinate"? Are you suggesting we find $k$ so that $T(x,y,z)=k\cdot z$ and then find a parametrization of $S^2$?

Comment: Exactly that. Put another way we can always choose polar coordinates $(\theta,\varphi)$ such that $T(\theta,\varphi)=k\cos(\varphi)$ for some $k>0$.

Comment: @Kajelad You mean $T(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta) = k \cos \theta$?

Comment: We can choose coordinates $(x,y,z)$ such that $T(x,y,z)=kz$. In polar coordinates $(x,y,z)=(r\cos(\theta)\sin(\varphi),r\sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi),r\cos(\varphi)$, this gives $T(r,\theta,\varphi)=kr\cos(\varphi)$. restricting to the sphere by setting $r=1$ then gives $T(\theta,\varphi)=\cos(\varphi)$.

Comment: That $k$ seems to depend on $\theta$ or $\phi$, or potentially even both. Is this not the case?

Comment: No. $k$ is constant in the expression $T=kz$, so we may substitute $z=r\cos(\varphi)$. I've edited the answer to include the setup of the integral.

Comment: The left hand side of your equality does not have the exponential factor, does this not affect the evaluation of the integral?

Comment: That was an oversight, it's now there.